# llamar a un modal por js dentro de un include

Tags: javascript, php, html, bootstrap

Tengo un modal en un archivo login.php ( unicamente el codigo del modal)  necesito que al loguerase ejecute la validación  en un archivo validar.php y al no poder hacerlo que automáticamente me levante si es posible el mismo modal pero lo voy a modificar para que muestre una advertencia que no se pudo loguear, el tema es que no se como hacer eso primero sin un botón, necesito que se abra automáticamente, y segundo que al tenerlo en un archivo y al invocarlo con un **include** no lo puedo abrir con js. se podrá hacer eso automáticamente? es decir llamar al modal desde php sin botón y que el mismo se encuentre en un include? yo lo que realicé fué devolver al index.php un error por get ,y ahí trato de imprimir por un echo un boton oculto y desde js leo ese boton e intente activar el modal, pero no funciana, la consola no muestra error pero debe ser que al tenerlo en un include.

Alguna idea?

```
  <?php   //VERIFICAR.PHP
$usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
$clave = $_POST['clave'];

include("conexion.php");

$consulta = mysqli_query($datos_bd, "SELECT pass FROM usuario WHERE email='$usuario'");

$codigo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta);

if (isset($codigo)){
    if(password_verify($clave, $codigo['pass'])) {
         header("Location: index.php");
    } else {
       header("Location: index.php?error");
    }
}else{
    
     header("Location: index.php?error");
}

?>
```

Y en el archivo login.php tenngo;

```
<!-- Modal login archivo login.php--> 
<div class="modal fade" id="ModalLogin" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header ">
        <span id="tituloFormLogin">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"></h5>
        </span>
        <button type="button" id="CloseModalLogin" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" ></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Inicio login -->
        <div id="login">
          <form action="verificar.php" method="POST" id="FormLogin" class="needs-validation" novalidate>
            <div class="mb-3 row">
              <label for="usrLogin" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Email</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="usrLogin" placeholder="nombre@ejemplo.com" name="usuario" required autofocus>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Por favor, ingrese su correo registrado.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3 row">
              <label for="inputPassword" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Password</label>
              <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="password" class="form-control" id="inputPassword" name="clave" maxlength="16" required>
                <div class="invalid-feedback">
                  Por favor, ingrese su password.
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="mb-3  row">
              <button class=" btn btn-primary" type="submit">Igresar</button>
            </div>
          </form>
          <span>¿No tienes cuenta? <a class="text-decoration-none" href="#" onclick="loadFormRegistro()">Regístrate</a></span> <br>
          <span><a class="text-decoration-none" href="#" onclick="loadFormRecupero()">Recuperar password</a></span>
        </div>
        <!-- Fin login -->
      <div class="modal-footer col align-self-end d-none" id="FooterModalLogin">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary " data-bs-dismiss="modal">Salir</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary " id="ButtonModalRecuperar">Registrar</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

y desde el index:

```
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"> </script>               

   if (isset($_GET['error'])){
                 echo "<button id='BtnError' class'd-none'></button>";
                  
                }
```

en el js

```
var error = document.getElementById('BtnError')


if (error !== null ){
  $('#ModalLogin').modal('show'); // abrir
}
```

Comment: No es más fácil y práctico devolver una respuesta en una alerta? Podés usar sweetalert por ejemplo

Comment: @RicardoPortillo yo le hiba a sugerir que se cambiara a .net de paso pero creo que no es lo que el quiere...

Comment: @Sergio Valdivia de lo que agregaste de codigo no veo cual es el que estas usando como intento ... has leido la documentacion de los modal o has investigado como se hace o que error tienes presisamente en tu codigo que no te permite que funcione.

Comment: Usar sweet alert es mucho mas practico bro, como ya dijeron arriba

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 ahí te agregue, ahora me estoy fijando que en consila me dice Uncaught TypeError: $(...).modal is not a function
    at main2.js:96:20 será que tengo mal los cdn? lei la documentacion de bootstrap y no lo pude resolver.

Comment: de por si no se si estas entendiendo como funciona el javascript el ajax y el php...

Comment: @MateoGuio y que es lo que esta pidiendo el usuario? que yo sepa el no esta pidiendo opiniones de si hay otra libreria mas facil de usar para hacer esto ...

Comment: LIsto gente! invesitgando estaba bien planteado pero esta llamado a abrir el modal fuera del load de Jquery, y debía ser adentro =) lo puse ahí y funciona todo como quería! gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Listo gente! investigando estaba bien planteado pero esta llamado a abrir el modal fuera del load de Jquery, y debía ser adentro =) lo puse ahí y funciona todo como quería! gracias!